How to access the metadata that malloc stores for each block?
I know that depending of the implementation of malloc, the algorithm used differs (free linked lists, buckets, binary buddy... - and often it is a mix).
So I was wondering if it is possible to know the size of the metadata stored by malloc for a certain block and access it even as a copy.
I have not found any standard function or method to do it.
Any idea?

There is no standard function for this. You need to look at the individual implementation of the C library you're using. Just curious: what do you want to do with that meta data or its size?

This is a very typical XY problem. Why do you need this information? What actual problem is it supposed to solve?

As you already wrote: "Depending on the implementation..." How would any standard function provide access to data that is not defined by the standard?

Usually it is accessible through wild & crazy pointer arithmetic as an offset of the address you received from malloc. But you need to know what implementation that is used in order to write a hack to inspect those bytes.

I don't "need" this information, it's purly informative. I am coding my own malloc and I was just wondering how much memory is used by a standard implementation of malloc (I mean, one which is well coded:) for each block.
Like, if I malloc(1), how much bytes are really used in memory?

@touikss from your last comment: you definitely need to look at some source code of malloc.

@touikss, for information about how malloc implementations operate, you would be better off reading documentation than attempting to probe (maybe-)observable behavior.  For instance, the Glibc docs contain some remarks about its allocator, and a link to a moderately details technical description.

There is no standard function to get the metadata for a malloc block, because as you correctly note, the location and contents of the metadata block are heavily implementation-dependent.
There are implementation-specific functions that you can use to get some information about heap blocks, for example, malloc_usable_size(void *ptr) in GNU libc. Other malloc implementation may support similar extensions.
